# Command line modify xml property with value defined inline

Tags: xml, bash, command-line, sed

I've got an xml property like so:

```
<property name="foo" value="bar"/>
```

And would like to modify the value "bar" to be anything else. Any standard command line tools to do so? I'm having trouble getting sed to play nice, I'm not sure which characters I should be escaping.

Answer (score 1):

[`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty full-featured XML tool.

```
xmlstarlet ed --update /property/@value -v qux <<END
<property name="foo" value="bar"/> 
END
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<property name="foo" value="qux"/>
```

Add `-O` to omit the XML declaration line.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the machine this is running on, so it's just standard tools for me :( sed, awk, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
echo '<property name="foo" value="bar"/>' | awk '{sub(/bar/,"new")}1'
<property name="foo" value="new"/>
```

another version

```
echo '<property name="foo" value="bar"/>' | awk -F\" '{$4="new"}1' OFS=\"
<property name="foo" value="new"/>
```